# apply chisq.test for contingency table over a dataframe using 4 row observations

Tags: r, chi-squared

I would like to run a chisq.test in R for 4 column values over several hundred rows. I would like a p value for differences in proportions. 
Here is the chi-square test I can run on its own but would like to apply it to a dataframe:

```
chisq.test(matrix(c(column1,column2,column3,column4), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))$p.value
```

- column1 = number of events for condition 1
- column2 = number of non-events for condition 1
- column3 = number of events for condition 2
- column4 = number of non-events for condition 2

I would like to apply this function to every row and output the p value into a new column called p_value.

I thought this would work:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
mutate(
p_value = chisq.test(matrix(c(column1,column2,column3,column4),byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)$p.value)
)
```

error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

have also tried:

```
new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(
p_val = mapply(
chisq.test, matrix(c(column1,column2,column3,column4), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)$p.value)
)
```

error: 'x' must at least have 2 elements

I know this has to be possible. Please help!

here is a subset of my data:

```
position    yes_condition1  no_condition1   yes_condition2  no_condition2
1   857 74  472 53  666
2   19557   46  241 70  294
3   23579   46  350 40  471
4   26837   42  155 31  131
5   28324   85  1128    164 1138
6   28537   29  141 23  60
```

Comment: Please provide some data

Comment: `dput(head(df))` if you have defined one. Or `fix(df)` So we can run it locally and if worked post the solution

Comment: I have provided some data.

Answer (score 3):

Using `rowwise` you can get p-value for each row in the following manner :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(p_value = chisq.test(c(yes_condition1, no_condition1, 
                                yes_condition2, no_condition2))$p.value)
```

However, instead of `rowwise` it is better to use `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(p_value = pmap_dbl(select(., -1),~chisq.test(c(...))$p.value))

#  position yes_condition1 no_condition1 yes_condition2 no_condition2      p_value
#1      857             74           472             53           666 6.98509e-188
#2    19557             46           241             70           294  2.03649e-60
#3    23579             46           350             40           471 8.65378e-136
#4    26837             42           155             31           131  4.75605e-28
#5    28324             85          1128            164          1138  0.00000e+00
#6    28537             29           141             23            60  3.96978e-30
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(position = c(857L, 19557L, 23579L, 26837L, 28324L, 
28537L), yes_condition1 = c(74L, 46L, 46L, 42L, 85L, 29L), no_condition1 = c(472L, 
241L, 350L, 155L, 1128L, 141L), yes_condition2 = c(53L, 70L, 
40L, 31L, 164L, 23L), no_condition2 = c(666L, 294L, 471L, 131L, 
1138L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: I assume map forces formulas into functions? am still working on reading the C code btw!

Comment: @user171558 Sorry, I didn't get you. What do you mean by `map forces formulas into functions` ?

Comment: I have usually seen `function(x) x+1` but with map people use ~ x +1. I asked about the source code of map and lapply yesterday for this purpose

Comment: yes `map` accepts both the ways, formula as well as anonymous functions. This is explained in `?map`.

Comment: The only change I made was: within the chisquared function, i used chisq.test(matrix(c(yes_condition1, no_condition1, 
                                yes_condition2, no_condition2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2))$p.value

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to add `p_value` column to the existing data frame

```
df$p_value <- apply(df[-1],1,function(x) chisq.test(matrix(x,nrow = 2))$p.value)
```

such that

```
> df
  position yes_condition1 no_condition1 yes_condition2 no_condition2      p_value
1      857             74           472             53           666 4.168176e-04
2    19557             46           241             70           294 3.385007e-01
3    23579             46           350             40           471 6.918144e-02
4    26837             42           155             31           131 7.040500e-01
5    28324             85          1128            164          1138 3.797607e-06
6    28537             29           141             23            60 7.140286e-02
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(position = c(857L, 19557L, 23579L, 26837L, 28324L, 
28537L), yes_condition1 = c(74L, 46L, 46L, 42L, 85L, 29L), no_condition1 = c(472L, 
241L, 350L, 155L, 1128L, 141L), yes_condition2 = c(53L, 70L, 
40L, 31L, 164L, 23L), no_condition2 = c(666L, 294L, 471L, 131L, 
1138L, 60L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Those p values are not correct. The "x" argument has to specify a 2x2 matrix (contingency table) for the correct chi sqared test to be performed.  Without the matrix, the chisq test does a goodness of fit test, rather than a pearsons chisquared test. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Kristin Thanks for the information. You can check my latest updates of my answer, which construct a 2-by-2 matrix, but not sure if the p-value is the right one you are after

Answer (score 0):

**DATA**

```
df <- mtcars[,1:4]
list <- apply(df,1,chisq.test)
sapply(list, function(x) x$p.value)
```

`apply()` is the base function you are looking. If you would like to perform a function across rows set the margin to 1.

Comment: The chisq.test function has many outputs. The fist code you submitted (before this edit) put the entire output in cell. This code spits out a list of all the output from every chisq.test that is run. This almost worked! But not quite. Thanks for trying!

Comment: `sapply()` is a base function that returns the output in a vector,matrix format. If you would like to use tidyverse, try `library(purrr);     map(list, ~ .x$p.value)` But tbh, am learning these things every day. R is great for data processing!